# Is window.setInterval correctly used here or am I introducing trouble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, window, setinterval

I have a search input`.searchinp` from a third party that I cannot modify. But I want to move the results from the left side of the page to the right side. I do this currently with a `setInterval`. The reason I used this `setInterval` is that the div that I want to move is not present on the page when it is loaded. Therefore I cannot simply move it at that point.

The user needs to fill in at least 3 letters before the results div`.dropdown-menu` is created.

So to make it move I used this:

```js
      window.setInterval(function(){
        /// call your function here
        $('.dropdown-menu').contents().appendTo('.knowledgebase-related-questions');
      }, 100);
```

Which works but I would like to know if there are drawbacks to doing this? Like website speed, slugginess or other drawbacks.

Comment: Are you able to add an event listener to the html element the user is typing in?

Comment: Performance? Likely not a problem. It may look odd if a user sees this before and after transition, though. You might be better off using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor the DOM directly and act immediately when it's changed.

Comment: @WesleySmith It already has an action attached to it. So I think not.

Comment: @purple11111 You can have as many as you need, adding an answer now

Comment: Frankly, it feels odd to use `setInterval` for this type of problem.
Attaching event listener on the element you are typing in should be a good solution.

Comment: @VLAZ I can surpress showing it until it is already moved. So no problem there. But indeed that would have looked strange!

Comment: @purple11111 well, if you're using CSS anyway, it might be possible to just move the entire container using CSS to the location you want. It would be in a different branch of the DOM tree (well, the original) but it's probably an even cheaper solution than JS.

Comment: Everyone I am going to try the eventListeren to see if I can implement that. As I agree that would be better then a interval. Never like using those.

Comment: @VLAZ moving by CSS I guess I missed a couple of classes? :-) Would you mind giving me a quick introduction to that?

Comment: @purple11111 hard to say *exactly* what you want but the simplest thing is to say `position: fixed` which will detach it from the normal flow and then set `right`/`left` and `top`/`bottom` which will position the container relative to the left/right and top/bottom edges of the screen. E.g, `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0` will anchor something in the top left corner. There are other positioning schemes that might also work for you `absolute` will make the element relative to the first non-static ancestor (still within a container). `relative` will move something relative to where it starts

Comment: @purple11111 you can check out for more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) or try "CSS position" in your search engine of choice - lots of resources for this. You're also welcome to ask specifically about what CSS can work for you but try to specify more details like a sample structure or an image of what you have and what you expect.

Comment: @VLAZ I know about that but in this case, it was that not a viable solution. But I do want to thank you for putting in the time to give me a quick introduction. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, Id add a listener to the input the user is typing in and set it up with a delay so my function is called X seconds after the user stops typing. Something like this:

```
var keyupDelay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})(); 


var inputSelector = '#some-id'; // adjust as needed 

$(inputSelector ).keyup(function() {
    keyupDelay(function(){
      // append or replace your html as needed
    }, 2500 ); // this will trigger 2.5 seconds after typing stops, adjust as needed
});
```

Comment: Typeaheads might act in different time, especially if they do a network call to get the suggestions. So, the delay might be too *small* and you get the results later or *too big* and you introduce unnatural delay.

Comment: @WesleySmith I tried your suggestion it worked and I like it a lot more than the `setInterval` so I am using this. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @VLAZ Indeed, this wont work well for some usages where result times vary widely etc.